# Can anyone help me with saving multiple array to the database in Yii2 framework?

Tags: php, arrays, yii2

I want to save the array to the database which the array is take from the DOMDocument I have created. I keep trying to save the array but it doesn't work. The database didn't show any data.  Below is the function I have create.

```
public function actionGetLme()
{
    $htmlContent = file_get_contents("https://www.lme.com/"); 

    $DOM = new \DOMDocument();
    @$DOM->loadHTML($htmlContent);

    $headerDOM = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('th'); //Getting the header of the table
    //#Get header name of the table
    foreach($headerDOM as $nodeHeader) 
    {
        $aDataTableHeaderHTML[] = trim($nodeHeader->textContent);
    }
    // print_r($aDataTableHeaderHTML);
    $shifted = array_shift($aDataTableHeaderHTML);
    //print_r($aDataTableHeaderHTML);

    #Get row data/detail table without header name as key
    $detailDOM = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('td');
    foreach($detailDOM as $sNodeDetail)  //Gettting the table data
    {
        $dataCell[] = trim($sNodeDetail->textContent);
    }
    // print_r($dataCell);
    $mapping[$shifted]=array_combine($aDataTableHeaderHTML,$dataCell);
    //print_r($mapping);
    $model = new Lme();
    $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()); 
    $model->lme_title = $shifted;              // The data that I want to save to the db
    $model->lme_name = $aDataTableHeaderHTML;  // The data that I want to save to the db
    $model->lme_price = $dataCell;             // The data that I want to save to the db
    $model->save();
```

The *$shifted* value is the top table header. Can refer to the link inside the code for more clearly understanding.

I already change the data to the array form. Below is the output of the DOMDocument which I get.

```html
Array
(
    [US$:  24 February 2020] => Array
        (
            [LME Aluminium] => 1,672.50
            [LME Copper] => 5,657.50
            [LME Zinc] => 2,039.00
            [LME Nickel] => 12,360.00
            [LME Lead] => 1,864.00
            [LME Tin] => 16,510.00
            [LME Aluminium Alloy] => 1,360.00
            [LME NASAAC] => 1,260.00
            [LME Cobalt] => 33,500.00
            [LME Gold*] => 1,674.30
            [LME Silver*] => 18.900
            [LME Steel Scrap**] => 290.00
            [LME Steel Rebar**] => 442.00
        )

)
```

I have create the database table with the lme_id, lme_title, lme_name and lme_price. I want to save the *$shifted* to the lme_title, *$aDataTableHeaderHtml* to lme_name, and *$dataCell* to lme_price.

```
Example : |lme_id|lme_title|lme_name|lme_price|
          |   1  |  Title  | Copper | 1660.00 |
```

Hope someone can teach me how to save the array into the database by using Yii2 framework. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing something important like which **database manager** you are using, for example, **MySQL, mssql, RDBMS**.

But just to notice not many **DBMS** allows you to save an array directly into the database, cause normal data types to be stored in databases are practical *primitive values*.

So, If this is the case, you could apply to methods around this:

---

**The first one** is to use the PHP [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) method to generate a string value which can then be saved into the database as you would do whit normal VARCHARS fields.

This method has some concerns which are by which I would not recommend this.

For example, 
1- The complex string being formed is difficult to read. 
2- You would end up needing to use a flag value to determinate the break and another value added to the array could cause problems with the flag you are using.

---

**The second method**, which is what I would recommend is to store as a **JSON** value.

Many DBMS support this type of data nowadays, and also it is a standardized format so what you could do in PHP is first to make a `json_encode(YOUR_ARRAY)` and then stored in the database.

[json_encode docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)
[json_decode docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

I'm not sure about the Yii part cause I haven't used it for quite some time. But I hope this information can guide you.

Comment: Thanks, I'm now going to try using the JSON_encode in my coding.

Comment: Sure, this is a good approach. Could you mark this question as to the accepted solution if it helps you to solve your doubts?

Comment: Using the Json_decode can change the string array to int array? Because now my $dataCell value is in the string[] format.